# Getting data from xml to insert into html tag but It is not seen in source code

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, xml, ajax

Getting data from xml to insert into ul tag. When I run the code, page is loading and I can see images on browser but jquery codes are not working (ex. click to #GalleryList element) because appended codes are not seen browser view source. How can I find solution?

JS:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "data.xml",
        dataType: "xml",
        success: function (xml) {
            var items = [];
            $(xml).find("item").each(function (i) {
                items.push({
                    img: $(this).find("img").text(),
                    content: $(this).find("content").text()
                });
                $('#GalleryList').append('<li>' + items[i].img + '</li>');
                $('#GalleryDetail').append('<li><div class="detailLeft">' + items[i].img + '</div><div class="detailRight">' + items[i].content + '</div></li>');
                i++;
            });
            return items;
        }
    });
    var currentElem, lastElem;
    lastElem = $('#GalleryList li').last().index();
    $('#GalleryList li').click(function () {
        currentElem = $(this).index() + 1;
        $('#GalleryList').hide();
        $('.GalleryDetail').show();
        $('#GalleryDetail li').hide();
        $('#GalleryDetail li:nth-child(' + currentElem + ')').show();
        pageControl();
    });
});
```

HTML:

```
<ul id="GalleryList" class="clearfix">

</ul>
<div class="GalleryDetail">
   <ul id="GalleryDetail">

   </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Elements added to the page on the client side will never be visible in the source. The source only displays what the source of the page is, meaning what it was returned from the server as.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use event delegation since the `li` elements are created dynamically

```
$('#GalleryList').on('click, 'li', function () {
    currentElem = $(this).index() + 1;
    $('#GalleryList').hide();
    $('.GalleryDetail').show();
    $('#GalleryDetail li').hide();
    $('#GalleryDetail li:nth-child(' + currentElem + ')').show();
    pageControl();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `$.on("click",..` and not `$.click`. http://api.jquery.com/on/

Answer (score 0):

You should use [on](http://api.jquery.com/on/) to bind event to element dynamically created:

```
$('#GalleryList li').on('click', function ()
```